# Connect two points in a smooth manifold with an embedding of $[0,1]$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying Jack Lee's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and there is this exercise

> Show that any two points in a connected smooth manifold can be joined by a smooth curve segment.

I did the exercise, but my curve wasn't regular. I was wondering if the curve could be made regular. Is it possible or is there a counterexample?

Comment: It's definitely always possible - one (indirect and overpowered) way is to choose a complete Riemannian metric and use a geodesic.

Comment: What if the manifold is not complete?

Comment: Completeness is a property of a metric, not a manifold. Every manifold admits a complete metric. Proving this (and the existence of regular geodesics), however, is a lot more work than this result should require, so I don't think it's a good answer to this question.

Comment: I meant geodesically complete with respect to a given metric, but I did not know that every manifold admits a complete metric. So the result is true... Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'regular'? Do you mean smooth?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $f: [0,1] \to M$ with $f'(t) \neq 0$ for each $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Here's a suggested approach: First show that you can connect any two points with a _piecewise regular_ curve segment, for example by using straight line segments in coordinates. Then use bump functions in coordinates near each nonsmooth point to "round the corner" while maintaining regularity.

Comment: @JackLee: How do you show that you “round the corner” without sacrificing regularity?

Comment: @pyon: That's the whole point of using a bump function. For example, to round the corner on the graph of $f(x)=|x|$, you could choose a smooth bump function $\phi$ such that $\phi(x) = 1$ for $x\in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ and $\text{supp}\,\phi\subseteq [-2\varepsilon,2\varepsilon]$, and define $\widetilde f(x) = (1-\phi(x))f(x)$.

Comment: @JackLee: Oh, the idea of using a bump function *did* occur to me, but... wait, isn't your $\tilde f$ constant in a neighborhood of $x = 0$?

Comment: @JackLee: More precisely, a parametrization of the graph of $f(x) = |x|$ is more like $\gamma(t) = (t, |t|)$. AFAICT, your regularization uses the fact that one of the coordinates of $\gamma$ is already a regular function of $t$, so you can afford to let the other coordinate be locally constant near $t = 0$.

Comment: @pyon: My example was just meant to serve as an illustration of how bump functions can be used to create a smooth curve. You'll have to do a little extra work to adapt it to the situation in the exercise.

Comment: @JackLee: I see, thanks!